# SQL - Change value on Row 3 when Case condition is met on Row 1

Tags: sql, oracle, case, conditional-statements

Am using SQL Oracle and trying to find out, based on below data set, how can I update row 3 when condition is met on row 1?

Rule is: If Check = Y then "On the 2nd month after, Glidepath = Y".

The key is code A.

```
Code   | Month      | Check  | Glidepath
-------| -----------| ----- -|----------
A      | 01/02/2017 | Y      | N
A      | 01/03/2017 | N      | N
A      | 01/04/2017 | N      | Y
A      | 01/05/2017 | N      | N
```

Any idea?

I have been trialing with Case statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know much about oracle syntax but apparently LAG and LEAD are available since version 8.1.6: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

What you want to do is update the table for rows with a where clause evaluating the following:

```
LAG(Check,2) OVER (partition by Code order by month) = 'Y'
```

That way the expression will be true for each Code where the Month is 2 down from the Month with check = y.

Let me know if it works, I only ever work with SQL Server.

Had this been SQL Server the code would be

```
UPDATE t
SET Glidepath = 'Y'
FROM dbo.table as t
WHERE LAG(t.[Check],2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Code] ORDER BY t.[MONTH]) = 'Y'
```

Edit: Oto pointed out in the comments that this only works if you have every month represented in the dataset. If you have to check the exact date use this instead (and if you only care about year+month part convert each value for [Month] to the appropriate granularity):

```
/*what is the dateadd equivelent in oracle? ADD_MONTHS?*/
UPDATE t1
SET Glidepath = 'Y'
FROM dbo.[table] AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[table] AS t2 WHERE t2.[Month] = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, t1.[MONTH]) AND t2.[Code] = 'Y')
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I should have thought about Lag/Lead! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @David - and what if there is not all month, for example there are only: `2017-04,
2017-05,
2017-11`. In this case, after 2 month from `2017-04` will be `2017-11`. isn't?

Comment: @Oto I didn't assume any inferred functionality from the month field, I interpreted the question as "the row 2nd from the one with Code='Y' when ordered by the column Month".